# Locate hidden .env and .gitignore file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hidden-files

I'm attempting to reveal my .env and .gitignore file in my rails application so I can set some variables within my applications environment. Idk why it's not in the root path of my application. Any advice would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following shell command in your rails root directory:

```
find . -type f -name '.[^.]*'
```

That will list all hidden files in that directory, and any subdirectory.